# Why can a Python script file not be named abc.py?

Tags: python, pycharm

One day when messing with Python in PyCharm, I encountered a quite silly problem. Namely, when I try to run a simple script in a file named `abc.py`, I receive an error. I tried to run the same file directly from the terminal and it looks fine.

**abc.py**

```py
print("Hello world")
```

**Output:**

```
/Users/.../venv/bin/python /Users/.../abc.py
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../abc.py", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: lost sys.stdout

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Just out of curiosity, what is the matter here?

EDIT:
Why does it happen only when running from PyCharm, and not when from the terminal?

Comment: abc is a default Python module, it might have something to do with that.

Comment: As you can see in the source code of [the io module, on line 52](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/io.py#L52), it imports the `abc` module of the standard library. If your file is named `abc.py`, it will be imported instead.

Comment: as others have been saying.  the flip side is also:  don't use built-ins for variable/function names.  if you have `list =2`, now you can't access the `list` function, as in `v = list({1,2,3})`.  the term for that is *shadowing*.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I've added a bonus question, because I feel like this matter wasn't answered yet.

Answer (score 6):

`abc` is standard module of python. Here => https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

It should works if you rename your own module abc.py in something else like abcd.py

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because python is confused.

You see, there is a built in module in python, that is *also* called **abc**(short for 'Abstract Base Classes')!

I suggest you name your file something else, or the other *crazy* way,

delete the module (just kidding, don't do that!).